# Please review my Python recursion snippet

Tags: python, recursion

The problem:

Given a string S, compute recursively a new string where identical characters that are adjacent in the original string are separated from each other by a "*".

Example:

```
Input = hello

Output = hel*lo
```

My code:

```
def pairStar(s):
    if len(s)<=1:
        return s
    if s[0]==s[1]:
        return s[0]+"*"+pairStar(s[1:])

string=input()
print(pairStar(string))

My input: hello

My output: None
```

Please help! The output shows "None" instead of "hel*lo".

Comment: For reviews of working programs, there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are not returning in every situation

Answer (score 5):

You're missing another `return` call in case the string is longer than 1 and the first 2 characters aren't a matching pair:

```py
def pairStar(s):
    if len(s)<=1:
        return s
    if s[0]==s[1]:
        return s[0]+"*"+pairStar(s[1:])
    return s[0] + pairStar(s[1:])

string=input()
print(pairStar(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer

```
def pairStar(s,start):
    if len(s)<=1:
        return s
    if start+1 >= len(s):
        return s
    if s[start] == s[start+1]:
        s = s[:start+1]+"*"+s[start+1:]
        return pairStar(s,start+2)
    else:
        return pairStar(s,start+1)

string=str(input("Enter the string:"))
start = 0
print(pairStar(string,start))
```